# Oh my zsh - exclude widgets from completion results

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

I'm really like AUTOCD option in zsh but widget names make it less comfortable in use. The problem is when I'm e.g. in my home directory, type "down" and press Tab I would expect completion for "Downloads" but on the first place in auto-completion is "down-line-or-beginning-search". Downloads is on the second pace what cause that I have to press tab additionally twice. It makes this process not to much ergonomic. 
Does anybody know how to exclude widget names from zsh auto-completion?

Comment: Usually widgets are not part of the tab-completion for commands (because they should/can only be run within `zle` not on their own). Did you perchance create a function named `down-line-or-beginning-search` in order to override the predefined widget of the same name?

Comment: Nope, I didn't create any functions. I think that it can be oh-my-zsh issue because the only things which I already have installed are zsh and oh-my-zsh with its default setting in .zshrc file.

Answer (score 0):

`zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' ignored-patterns 'down-line-or-beginning-search'`